# Read file to string with coffeescript and node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, fs

I try to read local file with coffescript and node.js. My code:

```
fs = require('fs')

foo = () ->
  return (fs.readFileSync config, 'utf8')
```

File is not empty. But when i call `foo` i got empty string. How can i read file to string correctly?

Thank you

Comment: Is that the whole program? What is `config`?

Comment: No, just part. `config` is file path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what you're doing wrong as you only show part of your program, but here is a demonstration of a similar program working.

test.txt:

```
testing
```

test.coffee:

```coffeescript
fs = require 'fs'
config = 'test.txt'

foo = ->
  fs.readFileSync config, 'utf8'

console.log foo()
```

Output:

```
$ coffee test.coffee
testing
```